# Django query for list of specimens of relations

Tags: django, model, aggregate

i need to get from db all specimens of relation from db. Currently i try to get this with

```
 Msg.objects.filter(Q(u1=request.user)|Q(u2=request.user))

U1 is a sender, U2 is a recipient. (Fields have forgeinkey, to User model)
```

This is app to sending messages between users. And i want create list of conversarions where current logged user is a U1 or U2, and get list to display without duplicates. Only one link for recipient / sender

Comment: so what problem are you facing?

Comment: This query get all relations, then on conversation list i have all messages.. i need only to get list conversation like facebook, conversation with user x, conversation with user y, user z, without duplicates

Comment: yes thats what you will get then loop through and put them inside a list, check if it exists in the list or not, if yes do not add them else append them

Comment: Hm, i can't do this in query? I dont want filter over 20K of messages in templates

Comment: limit it, like use a pagination, or eagerload, like fb uses, until click it wont show older messages,

Comment: But... Currenty i show list of all messages, for example: list of 20 messages with user x, 100 messages with user y, 10000 messages with user z

Comment: you can filter that message, like user x with user y,then user x and user z,wait i will give you an explanation for that

Answer (score 0):

According to the task description, proper solution would be:

```
Msg.objects.filter(Q(u1=request.user) | Q(u2=request.user)).distinct()
```